# Using qunit with web app in iframe

Tags: unit-testing, web-applications, qunit

I'm attempting to use qUnit to perform some unit testing that requires the screens generated by my web app to run. My idea is to put my application into an iframe embedded in my qUnit test page.  However this does not seem to work (in chrome) I don't seem to be able to access the web app's iframe.  If I do this in chrome's console I get undefined:

frames['myApp'].document

I think this is to do with some kind of cross domain scripting security but, both my web app and my test page are being served from localhost so I don't see why this is occurring, also I have started Chrome with the --disable-web-security parameter but this has not fixed.

Is there a better way to do unit testing that requires output from my application?

Comment: Please note that "my app" is actually a huge app that my company produces.  I do not have much scope to make massive changes to it to accommodate testing.  I am writing plugins for this app

Comment: I've noticed it works fine on IE...  Maybe I should just use IE *shudder*

Comment: possible duplicate of [UI-Test with QUnit, JQuery and an iframe - how to wait until new page is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773236/ui-test-with-qunit-jquery-and-an-iframe-how-to-wait-until-new-page-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

You can try publish these tests on localhost by any simple http server, for example if you have a node you can use https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server.

I have a similar situation tests are running in iframe and this work without problems.